How to append List to FormData in JQuery?
I get model's values from view with this codeblock and this part is OK.
var data = new FormData();

var datas = $(this).serializeArray();
for (var i = 0; i < datas.length; i++) {
    data.append(datas[i].name, datas[i].value);
}

In addition I want to add a list to data variable with this code block.
commentlist.push({ CommentID: commentguid, UserName: username, Comment: comment, MainCommentID: topcommentid });
data.append("Comments", commentlist);

And this is the list in my model from controller side.
public List<CommentModalClass> Comments { get; set; }

In summary I want to send commentlist to controllerside in data but I couldn't make it.

What exactly do you mean by "but I couldn't make it."? Was there an error? Did do something other than what you expected, and if so, what did it do?

@mykaf when I check it from controller side. Comments variable was null.

Did you check your Network tab to see if it was sent?

For passing the array of objects in FormData, the properties should be as below:
Comments[<index>].<Property name>

Thus it should be looked like:
Comments[0].CommentID: <commentguid>
Comments[0].UserName: <username>
Comments[0].Comment: <comment>
Comments[0].MainCommentID: <topcommentid>

for (let i = 0; i < commentlist.length; i++) {
  let comment = commentlist[i];
  for (let prop in comment) {
    data.append(`Comments[${i}].${prop}`, comment[prop]);
  }
}


Serialize the comments data in Jquery and send using Ajax call. For server side function definition should received a string and within that action method deserialize the data into your view model comments property i.e.
In JavaSript file:
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var comments = JSON.stringify(data)

    $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        url: '/MyController/GetCommentsData',
        data: { lstComments: comments },
        success:
            function (response)
            {
               // Success
               return response; 
            }
    });
});

In Your Code file:
...

Using Newtonsoft.Json

...

public bool GetCommentsData(string lstComments = "")
{
   // Initialization.
   bool isValid = true;
   MyModel model = new MyModel();

   // Verification
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lstComments))
   {
      // Fail.
      isValid = false;
      return = isValid;
   }

   // Deserialize Input JSON String into target Object Mapper.
   MyModel.Comments = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CommentModalClass>>(lstComments);

...
   
   // Process your Data.

...

   // Success.
   return isValid;
}

...

